# I don't understand how the progam works

Tags: java

in the book 'thinking in java' there is a code:

```
class Bowl {
    Bowl(int marker) {
        System.out.println("Bowl(" + marker + ")");
    }
    void f1(int marker) {
        System.out.println("f1(" + marker + ")");
    }
}

class Table {
    static Bowl bowl1 = new Bowl(1);
    Table() {
        System.out.println("Table()");
        bowl2.f1(1);
    }
    void f2(int marker) {
        System.out.println("f2(" + marker + ")");
    }
    static Bowl bowl2 = new Bowl(2);
}

class Cupboard {
    Bowl bowl3 = new Bowl(3);
    static Bowl bowl4 = new Bowl(4);
    Cupboard() {
        System.out.println("Cupboard()");
        bowl4.f1(2);
    }
    void f3(int marker) {
        System.out.println("f3(" + marker + ")");
    }
    static Bowl bowl5 = new Bowl(5);
}


public class StaticInitialization {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("create new object Cupboard() inside main");
        new Cupboard();
        System.out.println("create new object Cupboard() inside main");
        new Cupboard();
        table.f2(1);
        cupboard.f3(1);
    }
    static Table table = new Table();
    static Cupboard cupboard = new Cupboard();
}
```

I have some problems to understand how it works. For example why the line:

```
System.out.println("create new object Cupboard() inside main");
```

isn't first? Why Bowl bowl3 isn't static? What does it matter? Please explain, I'll be very grateful.

Output:

```
Bowl(1)
Bowl(2)
Table()
f1(1)
Bowl(4)
Bowl(5)
Bowl(3)
Cupboard()
f1(2)
create new object Cupboard() inside main
Bowl(3)
Cupboard()
f1(2)
create new object Cupboard() inside main
Bowl(3)
Cupboard()
f1(2)
f2(1)
f3(1)
```

Comment: You might want to read up on what `static` implies. That's the lesson here.

Comment: I've represented the writer's answer to your question, now in which part do you still have a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happens when you execute the `main()` method of `StaticInitialization` class:

1. Since `main()` is a `static` method of that class, so `StaticInitialization` class is loaded. And in turn all its `static` initializers are executed in order of occurrence.
2. First `static` field is `Table`. This loads the `Table` class.
3. Then the `static` fields of `Table` class is executed. Which loads `Bowl` class. There is no `static` initializers to be executed there.
4. Now, the `Bowl` constructor is executed for `new Bowl(1)` and `new Bowl(2)` you've in the `Table` class. This results in your first two print statements - `Bowl(1)` and `Bowl(2)`.
5. At this point of time, `Table` class is fully loaded, with all its `static` initializers executed. So now the `Table()` constructor is executed for the `new Table()` in `StaticInitialization` class.
6. Here comes the next output - `Table()` from the constructor, and then it invokes `bowl2.f1(1);`. Which prints `f1(1)`.
7. Till here, the first `static` initializer of `StaticInitialization` class is done. Now comes the turn of `Cupboard`.

I guess from hereon you can trace how the programs works. Just follow how the class is initialized, and what code of that class will be executed as part of its initialization.

> Why `Bowl bowl3` isn't static? What does it matter?

It makes a difference. Since the field is non-`static`, it will not be executed when the class `Cupboard` is loaded. That is why you see output from `Bowl(4)` coming before `Bowl(3)`. The non-`static` fields are initialized only when an instance of that class is created.

For more details, you may like to go through - [JLS §12.4 - Initialization of Classes and Interfaces.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)

Answer (score 0):

I still insist that you have to read the book more carefully!!! Who want's to answer with more details?

> Bowl allows you to view the creation of a class, and Table and Cupboard have static
>   members of Bowl scattered through their class definitions. Note that Cupboard creates a 
>   non-static Bowl bowl3 prior to the static definitions. 
>   From the output, you can see that the static initialization occurs only if it’s necessary. If you 
>   don’t create a Table object and you never refer to Table.bowl1 or Table.bowl2, the static 
>   Bowl bowl1 and bowl2 will never be created. They are initialized only when the first Table 
>   object is created (or the first static access occurs). After that, the static objects are not 
>   reinitialized. 
>   The order of initialization is statics first, if they haven’t already been initialized by a previous 
>   object creation, and then the non-static objects. You can see the evidence of this in the 
>   output. To execute main( ) (a static method), the Static Initialization class must be 
>   loaded, and its static fields table and cupboard are then initialized, which causes those
>   classes to be loaded, and since they both contain static Bowlobjects, Bowl is then loaded. 
>   Thus, all the classes in this particular program get loaded before main( ) starts. This is 
>   usually not the case, because in typical programs you won’t have everything linked together 
>   by statics as you do in this example.

To summarize the process of creating an object, consider a class called Dog:

1. Even though it doesn't explicitly use the static keyword, the constructor is actually
   a static method. So the first time an object of type Dog is created, or the first time a 
   static method or static field of class Dog is accessed, the Java interpreter must 
   locate Dog.class, which it does by searching through the class path.
2. As Dog.class is loaded (creating a Class object, which you’ll learn about later), all 
   of its static initializers are run. Thus, static initialization takes place only once, as 
   the Class object is loaded for the first time.
3. When you create a new Dog( ), the construction process for a Dog object first 
   allocates enough storage for a Dog object on the heap.
4. This storage is wiped to zero, automatically setting all the primitives in that Dog 
   object to their default values (zero for numbers and the equivalent for boolean and 
   char) and the references to null.
5. Any initializations that occur at the point of field definition are executed.
6. Constructors are executed. As you shall see in the Reusing Classes chapter, this might 
   actually involve a fair amount of activity, especially when inheritance is involved.

Comment: I read this book in Polish because I don't know English well, but there are a few mistakes in the translation.

Comment: @user3551849> Ok, that's another point. If that's so I suggest you to read the original version, this book is full of details and I'm a big fan of it.

Answer (score 0):

Bowl(int marker) {
   System.out.println("Bowl(" + marker + ")");}

Is what call constructor.. search on google for more.

void f1(int marker) {
   System.out.println("f1(" + marker + ")");}

is call method of the class..

I suggest you take any good book on java to clear concept of OOP first..
You will likely to get more questions ahead..if you go blindly..

Answer (score 0):

Inside `StaticInitialization` class you have..

```
static Table table = new Table();
    static Cupboard cupboard = new Cupboard();
```

1- you are creating Table object statically. which will be the first line of code to be executed.

2-  `static Bowl bowl1 = new Bowl(1);`
next lint would be inside table class, another static object is creating of Bowl class.

3-  `System.out.println("Bowl(" + marker + ")");` inside Bowl class would be executed next so this was the first `Sysout` to be printed in console.
static object will create first followed by `static` method that is `main` method.